# How to get insert/update row count at the end of mapping/Mapping task - IICS

Tags: mapping, informatica-cloud

Goal : Need to store row count of insert/update/delete/rejected in SQL Server table at the end of each Informatica mapping completes in cloud version - No powercenter.
I know in Powercenter you could get it from repo/metadata views. But in IICS cloud has no such objects to access I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IICS Rest API to get this info from repository

Rest API Reference, look at page 21 for your case
https://network.informatica.com/docs/DOC-17563

The following fields can be retrieved from API result

*failedSourceRows*

*successSourceRows*

*failedTargetRows*

*successTargetRows*

Comment: Thanks- 1) Per doc, I need to pass task id, activity log id or run id - where can I find/pull it from?   2)Do I need to use it in webservices/java component or something else in  mapping?  3) Insert/Update/Delete count can also be retrieved from api / informatica params?

Comment: If you are familiar with API calls, that's fairly easy to do this, if not there is some learning needed. Answers 1- You need to make a call for "login" using username and password, this will give you a session id, you can use taskflow/task name to make a second call to run the job 2 - This needs to happen outside the mapping, you can use java/python/shell scripts etc. 3 - Based on your "Target/Details/Operation" you'll have a target behaves as Insert/Update etc.

Comment: Thanks. My question was more on insert and update row counts. Are you aware of any way other than using expressions & variables to count to get the no. of rows inserted/updated?

Comment: Both in PowerCenter and IICS there is one target object, based on how you set it up  (in IICS "Target/Details/Operation") it could behave as either insert/update/delete. Let's say you have two targets in your IICS mapping, target1 is for insert and target2 is for update. `successTargetRows` for `target1` will give you `insert` row count and  `successTargetRows` for `target2` will give you `update` row count

Comment: Good point. Thanks. Ours is a DW means mostly upsert as data strategy so just one object. Any advise around that? –

Answer (score 0):

Within the IICS Taskflow, you use get the following "Output Parameters" from each Data Task in the TaskFlow:

- Failed Source Rows
- Failed Target Rows
- Run Id
- Success Source Rows
- Succes Target Rows

You might use an Assignment object to store these values in a Taskflow Parameter, but you could also use that same assignment object to pipe these values into an Input Parameter or a IO Parameter of another Data Task.

---

If you want separate numbers for insert and update, you might consider splitting up your mapping:

- One mapping which contains the logic and stores the data into 1 or 2 temporary tables
- One mapping which updates the records
- One mapping which inserts the records